# Could storing jpg images in coredata make iCloud App easier

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5, icloud

I have an iOS 5.1 application that made use of CoreData in iCloud.
The user can take pictures and save it on iCloud too.
At the moment I am only saving an attribute picture YES or NO in an entity which should represent the event of taking picture, let say it's a kind of diary.

When YES I can calculate the path and retrieve the images. Actually there are three jpg images saved, a small to be used in UITableCell, a medium size for iPhone and a big size for iPad.
The maximum size can be at its maximum roughly 100kb.

Everything works fine, but I had to put some heavy logic into the app, for example to decide whether or not the images goes to iCloud, and in case of deletion if the images can be deleted too or moved locally.

In my development life I have never choosed to save images or binary in a DB, but this time I was thinking if the CoreData synchronization happening in the background could make my app more solid, and let me remove some lines of code. The idea is to add three attributes to the entity or probably for lazy issues, in another entity to be loaded as needed.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would definately refrain from storing any image data in the database. I had an app that worked great where I stored thumbnails in the database. Once I attempted to move to iCloud I noticed a substantial increase in sync time due to the image data. I am talking several seconds to minutes if your database gets several entries. I am now storing everything in folders and testing diffrent ways to allow the user to decide which images they do or do not want saved in the cloud.

If your data entry will stay small I think it may stil be worth a shot, but develop know

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to store at least the small image in the DB. This should be very efficient, not be too network-intensive and - most importantly - would not make the iCloud store too big.

Apple is very adamant about "responsible" data storage in iCloud. See the section "[Being a Responsible iCloud App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1)" in the iOS Programming Guide. There it states

> Apps that take advantage of iCloud storage features should act responsibly when storing data there. The space available in each user’s account is **limited** and is **shared by all apps**.

Thus, I would refrain from storing large images in your iCloud core data store.